# I need help in PDO and JSON

Tags: javascript, php, android, json

I have a table with 3 column id, B_title, B_category like [this](http://hpics.li/465e982)

1. I want dynamically load Json data (for B_category column but without returning the duplicated value) into a ListView using PDO.
2. display for each row in listview his counter of duplicated values example

> Fiction       counter=3
>
> Humour        counter=3
>
> Business      counter=2

I want result of JSON array looks like this :

> {"books":[{"B_category":"Fiction","counter":"3"},{"B_category":"Humour","counter":"3"},{"B_category":"Business","counter":"2"}]}

Comment: I'm voting to put on hold, as the question is too dependent on external links. Everything the reader needs to understand your problem should be in the question itself (since if those links break in the future, the question will not be useful to anyone else). If you can modify it so that everything is in the question, and you make an attempt, I will cast a reopen vote on request. (Please don't mark your questions as urgent - readers don't generally like queue-jumping here. All well-written questions have equal value).

Comment: Also, Java != JavaScript - I've retagged.

Comment: sorry I speak very little English for that I did not well explained my problem .

Comment: Your English is OK, it is just that too many external links doesn't work well here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't show any initiative by not posting some code you tried.

First, learn to fetch data with PDO, then use json_encode().

Comment: I tried this code :      <?php 
require 'connection_pdo.php';

$conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT B_category FROM test1";
$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();
$row = array();

$row = $stmt -> fetchAll();

$json['books'] = $row;
echo json_encode($json);
?>

Comment: but is not that I wanted in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution. It works very well for me, enjoy :)

```
<?php 
require 'connection_pdo.php';
$conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$sql = "select column,count(*) as counter from table GROUP BY  column,column HAVING counter>0 ORDER BY RAND()  "; 
$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();
$row = $stmt -> fetchAll();
$json['xxx'] = $row;
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```